# “We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now” on cart add product

Tags: magento2

[image]How to resolve ???

I has changed in vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Cache\Backend\File.php:99

Change 'cache_dir' => null to 'cache_dir' => 'var/cache'. And not resolve this.

Plsssss help me !!! Thank Alls :D

Comment: You should not edit core classes instead you should override. I think you should check the product attributes on admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Go to admin panel and remove all price rule 
Then clear cache working fine

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you ever used amasty free item to cart extension and disabled, make sure to remove the rules that may still be trying to apply. They can't and will cause this if extension disabled. Also, I'm starting to think amasty sucks